# What Grouping Method To Determine Average Over Lifetime?

Tags: time-series, clustering, survival, econometrics, time-varying-covariate

I have the following data:

When individual 'x' joined a company. As the data is limited to 2 years I do not know the start date of every individual.
When individual 'x' left the same company. If this is 'today' then the individual has not left the company. 
I know the amount of revenue generated by individual 'x' per day.

I have about 500 individuals in total i.e. x = 1,2,3,4....500.

I want to determine the average lifetime revenue of an individual based on the data I have.

This is what I was thinking to do: 
1. Only consider individuals I have a complete 'lifetime revenue time series' for (ie know the start/end date)
2. Obtain a distribution for this data
3. Take the mean

The problem is that this ignores 'loyal' individuals who may have generated loads of money daily and have been at the company for years and years. It also may skew the answer because you may have individuals who start/leave on the same day (this is common).

How would you approach this problem? The thinking behind this is to select a bucket of individuals and follow them over a lifetime to figure out the revenue. I think this may be a type of survival analysis but I'm slightly unsure and looking for some help.

Comment: Have you thought about interval regression?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **fitting distributions to censored data**.

Essentially, there are approaches to fit a distribution even when you do not have complete data, but your data is truncated at some point. Here, the truncation will be when users have not yet quit - this is "censored" from your analysis.